# Etag generation with RestEasy

Tags: java, web-services, resteasy, etag

My question is quite simple : is there a way to generate an ETag on a GET request using Java/RestEasy ?

In my mind, I'm searching for a simple-elegant annotation in the way of @Cache{param0=val0, param1=val1}

Someone know how to do that ? Any advice ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My advice is to read the documentation ;) http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.4.Final/userguide/html_single/#server_cache